# Can't read body parameter in Express for POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having trouble access the body parameters of a request with express:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

require('./app/routes/auth.routes')(app);
require('./app/routes/user.routes')(app);


const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8000'
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on http://loclalhost:${port}`));
```

The route I am trying to hit is: `http://loclalhost:8000/api/auth/signup`

[image]

Within the route I try to access the body like so:

```
const user = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8)
});
```

However I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please share where did you use `user`?
In the postman image, can you change Text to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is not in reading the body parsed data, as it says user and not username. Can you please share the complete code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm well my guess is the order how you wrote your code. Imagine the code goes from the top to the bottom, so you access the app routes before you parse the body. Try it like this, swap the order:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8000'
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

require('./app/routes/auth.routes')(app);
require('./app/routes/user.routes')(app);
```

Its also a common way to use the express router like this for example:

```
const routes = require("./routes/routes.js");

app.use(routes);
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion 
Change :

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` 
to 
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`

and use `x-www-form-urlencoded`